# Spring Security - Authenticate user with username

Tags: java, spring-boot, authentication, spring-security, jwt

I want to authenticate user with username only. To achieve this, I am still using `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken`but by also passing added authorities.

 Here is the code:

```
List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN"));
Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(
    new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username,null,authorities)
);
```

This unfortunately throws bad credentials exception. What am I missing here?
When replacing the code above with correct password for the username, it works perfectily.

```
Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(
    new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username,password,authorities)
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to use the `AuthenticationManager` if you already know they are authenticated. **Instead you can just set the `Authentication` directly as shown below:**

```java
List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN"));
Authentication authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, null, authorities);
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, @ismail, I tried this and it worked.

```
refreshTokenService.validateRefreshToken(refreshTokenRequest.getRefreshToken());
User user = userRepository.findByUsername(refreshTokenRequest.getUsername());
List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = new ArrayList<>();
user.getRoles().forEach(role -> grantedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getRoleName())));
Authentication authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user.getUsername(), null, grantedAuthorities);
return AuthenticationResponse.builder()
         .authenticationToken(jwtUtil.generateToken(authentication))
         .refreshToken(refreshTokenRequest.getRefreshToken())
         .username(user.getUsername())
         .build();
```